# How to stop AdMob using cpu when Android application is closed?

Tags: android, admob

When I enable ads in my app and close it with finish()/back button/with normal ways. My app continues to use cpu. I couldn't figure out the problem until I removed Admob View.

Why does it happen? How can I prevent this?

Comment: Do you have in your code     `if (adView != null) {adView.destroy();}`? Do it at onDestroy. Please show what you have done.

Comment: @AlexBcn Please post this as an answer so I can accept it; I haven't that line in my onDestroy. Putting it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add on your code

```
if (adView != null) {
  adView.destroy();
}
```

Do it at `onDestroy` of your activity.